# Variety of ways to reading and writing to files and data streams in c#?

Tags: c#, file, stream, streamreader

I want to read by Character to Character from files and data streams. and need to sets the position within the current stream.

I know The System.IO namespace is for do this. and For to do this exist variety of classes, such as

StreamReader class,

TextReader class,

Stream class,

BinaryReader class,

FileStream class,

I want to know what's other Variety of ways for to do it in C# and which is best? and why?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the base class [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) for reading and writing, you can let your user pass you one as a parameter to your reading or writing function. That way, your caller can decide if he wants to read or write from a file, the network, memory or something else.

The inheritance hierarchy at the bottom of the linked site says right now there are a lot of implementations your caller can chose from:

```
  Microsoft.JScript.COMCharStream
  System.Data.OracleClient.OracleBFile
  System.Data.OracleClient.OracleLob
  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream
  System.IO.BufferedStream
  System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream
  System.IO.Compression.GZipStream
  System.IO.FileStream
  System.IO.MemoryStream
  System.IO.Pipes.PipeStream
  System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream
  System.Net.Security.AuthenticatedStream
  System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
  System.Printing.PrintQueueStream
  System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream
```